# Merge rows in column header for ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have stumbled upon a problem while creating my **SSRS** report. I want to be able to display my table headings as depicted in the following image:

[image][image]

I can't seem to get it right, I have tried using a group and adding rows inside that group as a work around but haven't found a solid solution towards the problem.

I am not an expert in **SSRS** but have worked on some reports. Any expert advise will be much appreciated.

Comment: All cells contain static data?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the final output you desire. You say this must be a header but unless I see the context of the other data it's hard to come up with a solution.

Comment: All data is static, will update image quickly @AlanSchofield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a table nested in another like the image below.

The nested table(table in gray color) can have static or even dynamic data

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried, will quickly give it a go and let you know.